# Why does Objective-C runtime library use C++ ABI for exception handling?

Tags: objective-c, exception, objective-c++, objective-c-runtime

I saw at http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-532.2/runtime/objc-exception.mm that Apple's Objective-C runtime uses some C++ ABI functions for exception handling, like `__cxa_throw`, `__cxa_begin_catch`, `__cxa_end_catch` and `__cxa_rethrow`. Because exception handling in Objective-C is similar to exception handling in C++ (even the C++ personality routine is the same for Obj-C), it's necessary only a few adaptations to use those functions in the Objective-C runtime library.

So, my point is, runtime team "does not need" or it "can not" (maybe to keep compatibility with C++, for Objective-C++) implement its own ABI (by using the Unwind library, for example, like C++ ABI does)? Do functions like `objc_exception_throw`, `objc_exception_rethrow`, `objc_begin_catch` and `objc_end_catch` have to deal with C++ objects, so that they not only can, but must use `__cxa_throw`, `__cxa_rethrow`, `__cxa_begin_catch` and `__cxa_end_catch` under the hood, like they actually do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect Apple chose to use those C++ ABI functions in order to increase the interoperability between C++ and Objective-C exceptions. IIRC, in the "modern" Objective-C runtime (available on iOS and Mac OS X 64-bit), C++ can catch Objective-C exceptions and vice-versa. In earlier incarnations of the runtime that was not the case, which led to very annoying problems when combining C++ and Objective-C code in the same application.

Comment: Exactly correct;  the modern runtime has a unified exception model because the modern runtime did not have binary compatibility requirements and, thus, the runtime team could make architectural changes that were not possible while maintaining binary compatibility (this also includes non-fragile ivars).